# create a loop function in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have a table include three fields tblUser(ID, parentID,count). parentID references tblUser(ID)

I want create function with parameter is ID in table. The function will select `parentID` and set `count = count + 1 where ID = parentID`.

I want to use `while loop` or `for()` to repeat the action `until ID == parentID`

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to avoid using loops in SQL. It's better to deal with data as a set rather than a row at a time, as loops are far more resource intensive.

Also, in the example you have given you haven't stated why you need to use a loop. It seems in this case it would be easier to simply say

```
set Count = ParentID
```

Now that I have warned you off using a loop, here's a simple example of a while loop:

```
Declare @Count integer = 0
  ,@ParentID integer

Select @ParentID = ParentID From Table 
(your where clause goes here)

While @Count <= @ParentID
BEGIN

  (whatever you want to do in your loop)
  Set @Count = @Count + 1

END
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your problem, couldn't you just do it in a single statement?

```
update theTable
set count = count + 1
where ID = parentID
```

As Aidan said, generally you do NOT want to loop in SQL, nor do you generally *need* to.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a declarative language, you tell it what you want and let the query engine decide how best to do it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IncrementCount @parentID int
AS
UPDATE theTable
SET count = count + 1
WHERE ID = parentID
```